# Angular error ngsw-worker.js Mixed Content

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

In the server in the first realod, throw Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.expample.net/example/ngsw-worker.js' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://example.example.net/example/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS, when reload the pages the error disappears

Remove all the http links in the code, any advice

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.